# Email validation n vuetify.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an email field

```
    <template>
  <v-form v-model="valid">
    <v-text-field
      label="Name"
      v-model="name"
      :rules="nameRules"
      :counter="10"
      required
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
      label="E-mail"
      v-model="email"
      :rules="emailRules"

    ></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

and validation rule like,

```
 <script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      valid: false,
      name: '',
      nameRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Name is required',
        v => v.length <= 10 || 'Name must be less than 10 characters'
      ],
      email: '',
      emailRules: [ 
        v => /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid'
      ]
    })
  }
</script>
```

but it validate form whnever i submit the form, i need to validate email only when email.length>0 . ie email is not a required field, but if email typed , it must be validate.

also tried,
when i change `:rules="[emailRules.em]"`  like this and in script

```
emailRules: { 
                        em:v => {
                        if(v.length > 0 && /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) )
                            return ''E-mail must be valid';  
                          return true;
                    }
                    }
```

it always return true

Comment: You would write a simple function and nest this within the code such that it only executes when the email length is not 0, for example. Was your question regarding the programming syntax of going about with such code? Or the general method to go about? Or was it that you had such a function but it doesn't work the way you expect it to work? The question wasn't clear in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @onlyphantom , i edited the code, here email validation works on submit,even am not enter any email. But i nedd validation only if email is typed ant not in correct format.

Comment: Why not use a simple inpuyt Email required property as following in the exemple there: `var x = document.getElementById("myEmail").required;`

Comment: hi @EmileCantero, i dont nedd email as required field, need only the format validation if email entered

Answer (score 24):

Just add the condition !v at the begining of your rule :

```
 emailRules: [ 
        v => !v || /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid'
      ]
```

Comment: Note that a TLD can be longer than 3 characters an this current regex will reject them. E.g. "john.doe@company.asia" won't match the regex although .asia is a valid TLD

Comment: referring to @Freggar's comment just incase anyone doesn't know changing the portion that says w{2,3} to w{2,4} would fix it, & .asia would be accepted.

emailRules: [ 
        v => !v || /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid'
      ]

Comment: This pattern doesn't allow for + signs in the email address, such as test+1@gmail.com

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at that..

```
emailRules: [ v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'Invalid Email address' ]
```

Comment: this is good, i really like simplicity - but be careful to match ^ and $ - for me this works well enough: /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$/

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
email: value => {
      if(value.length > 0) {
      const pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return pattern.test(value) || 'Invalid e-mail.';
      }
    }
```

Comment: This rejects quite a lot of obscure, but entirely valid email addresses. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Answer (score 2):

I've put my function in watch like this and only apply email rules when not empty like this:

Template:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="e_Mail"
    :rules="emailRules"
    prepend-icon="mail"
    label="Email Address"
></v-text-field>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            e_Mail: '',
            emailRules:[],
        }
    },
    watch: {
        e_Mail: function (mail) { // e_Mail is the exact name used in v-model
            if (mail !== '') {
                this.emailRules = [ v => (v.match(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)) || 'Invalid Email address']
            } else if (mail === '') {
                this.emailRules = []
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This worked for me, hope it works for you :)